# Poetry package changes vertical space around section headings in strange ways

Tags: sectioning, section-titles, poetry

Using the `poetry` package, I'm having trouble getting a consistent space around my section titles. All my poems start with a title, given as a `\section`. Sometimes two poems are set on the same page. Sometimes a poem runs over more than one page (the current `poem`-environment is then paused with `\\*`, a pdf with a picture is included and the poem is re-started with `\*`  at the start of the first line). This, however, causes a change in the space before the title. That is, the distance from "overflow text" and a title is smaller than between a poem that starts and ends on the same page, and the section title below.

Plain text does not cause this. That is, if a page starts with ordinary text, then a new section, the space before the section title is the same as if the page started with a new section.

The space *after* a section title changes depending on whether the title is followed by a poem or by ordinary text, but at least that's consistent, it doesn't change depending on overflow or not. But something causes the `poem` environment to gobble up a small but noticeable bit of space before the next title if it's split over two pages, compared to when it's contained on one page.

The MWE is kinda long, because I wanted to show all different combinations. The difference in space around sections 2 and 3 is the main problem -- the other sections are there for contrast. Please note that the `poetry` package seems to collide with another package when downloaded to MikTeX, so it might not compile if you run it locally. Viewable Overleaf example here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/qggmxspxsxms

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{poetry}\poemlinenumsfalse
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{The very first, -/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\*

\newpage
\* Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{First, P/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{Following, P/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}


\newpage
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{First, T/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{Following, P/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\newpage
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{First, T/T}
Text Text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text


\section{Following, T/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text


\section{Following, T/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\newpage
\section{Top of page, T/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\*

\newpage

\* Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{First, P/T}
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{Following, T/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}


\section{Following, P/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is a poem

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to figure out just what your spacing problem was. I have never used the `poetry` package. I don't know if this will be of any help. I changed your code to use the `verse` package (warning I developed it) instead of the `poetry` package and used the `verse`  `\poemtitle{...}` instead of `\section{...}` for the titles of poems.

```
% poemprob.tex  SE 640836

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}

%\usepackage{poetry}\poemlinenumsfalse
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\poemtitle{The very first, -/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\*

\newpage
\* Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{First, P/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{Following, P/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}


\newpage
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\poemtitle{First, T/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{Following, P/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}

\newpage
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{First, T/T}
Text Text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text


\section{Following, T/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text


\section{Following, T/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\newpage
\poemtitle{Top of page, T/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\*

\newpage

\* Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}

\section{First, P/T}
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\poemtitle{Following, T/P}
\begin{verse}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{verse}

\section{Following, P/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is a poem

\end{document}

%%%%%% ORIGINAL MWE FOLLOWS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

{poetry}\poemlinenumsfalse
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{The very first, -/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\*

\newpage
\* Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{First, P/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{Following, P/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}


\newpage
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{First, T/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{Following, P/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\newpage
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{First, T/T}
Text Text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text


\section{Following, T/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text


\section{Following, T/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\newpage
\section{Top of page, T/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\*

\newpage

\* Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}

\section{First, P/T}
Type-setting is a nightmare

This is plain text

\section{Following, T/P}
\begin{poem}
Poem poem, please behave\\
So my peace of mind you save\\
Type-setting is a nightmare\\
This is a poem\\-
\end{poem}


\section{Following, P/T}
Text text, please behave

So my peace of mind you save

Type-setting is a nightmare

This is a poem

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. In the documentation of poetry, there is \poemtopskip and \poembotskip which manage spaces before and after the environment.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640836/poetry-package-changes-vertical-space-around-section-headings-in-strange-ways/640918#640918
    \usepackage{poetry}\poemlinenumsfalse
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \usepackage{paracol}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    Default
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section{With the environment poem}
        \begin{poem}
            Poem poem, please behave\\
            So my peace of mind you save\\
            Type-setting is a nightmare\\
            This is a poem\\-
        \end{poem}
        \textbf{Some text}
        \switchcolumn
        \section{Without the environment poem}
        Poem poem, please behave

        So my peace of mind you save

        Type-setting is a nightmare

        This is a poem

        \textbf{Some text}
    \end{paracol}

    \rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
    Modified

    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section{With the environment poem}
        \poemtopskip=0pt%<---- modif 1em by default
        \poembotskip=0pt%<---- modif 1em by default
        %\setlength{\poemindent}{1in}%<---- for the indent 0pt by default
        \begin{poem}
            Poem poem, please behave\\
            So my peace of mind you save\\
            Type-setting is a nightmare\\
            This is a poem\\-
        \end{poem}
        \textbf{Some text}
        \switchcolumn
        \section{Without the environment poem}
        Poem poem, please behave

        So my peace of mind you save

        Type-setting is a nightmare

        This is a poem

        \textbf{Some text}
    \end{paracol}
    \end{document}
```

[image]